# Celery for Testing Configuration in Django

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a file celery_test.py which should load the configuration settings for testing(config.test) in Django but instead, it loads configuration of Development(config.development)

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from django.conf import settings
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault(
"DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.testing"
)


test_app = Celery('test')
test_app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
test_app.autodiscover_tasks()

print("Testing celery")
print(settings)

@test_app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

When I am printing settings it printing `config.development` instead of `config.testing`. Can anyone help me here how to load `config.testing`?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that you use django I would suggest not actually overriding the settings file like this. Instead use the `django.test.override_settings` decorator to override the specific settings you want to change. This way you're always testing the most current settings file, so you don't have to keep both up-to-date.

More information is also in the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.override_settings.

I can't really provide an example, since you don't provide any unittest example. But I hope the linked documentation is clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your are using `pytest`, you could put this in your `pytest.ini` file:

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = celery_test.py
```

Or use:

```sh
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=celery_test.py pytest
```

for a one-liner.